# fastlane build iOS apps get some error

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastlane

When i try to build apps by fastlane,i got some error..
Like this:

```
[15:37:03]: Using version: 1.4.3
[15:37:03]: Using build: 100
[15:37:03]: Using channel_id: Sina2
[15:37:03]: -------------------------------------------------
[15:37:03]: --- Step: Verifying required fastlane version ---
[15:37:03]: -------------------------------------------------
[15:37:03]: fastlane version valid
[15:37:03]: ------------------------------
[15:37:03]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[15:37:03]: ------------------------------
[15:37:03]: Driving the lane 'ios Channel' 
[15:37:03]: -----------------------
[15:37:03]: --- Step: cocoapods ---
[15:37:03]: -----------------------
[15:37:03]: [SHELL COMMAND]: pod install
[15:37:03]: Variable Dump:
[15:37:03]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:ios, :PLATFORM_NAME=>:ios, :LANE_NAME=>"ios Channel"}
[15:37:03]: No such file or directory - pod


/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:25:in `popen': No such file or directory - pod (Errno::ENOENT)
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:25:in `sh_no_action'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:8:in `sh'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/actions/cocoapods.rb:27:in `run'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:142:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:37:in `execute_action'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:128:in `block in execute_action'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:127:in `chdir'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:127:in `execute_action'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:134:in `method_missing'
  from (eval):116:in `block (3 levels) in parse'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:48:in `call'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:48:in `block in execute'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:46:in `chdir'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:46:in `execute'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:43:in `cruise_lane'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:31:in `handle'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/bin/fastlane:36:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:428:in `run_active_command'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:68:in `run!'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/bin/fastlane:127:in `run'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.29.2/bin/fastlane:133:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
  from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Format the question properly (in terms of indentation) and post the line of code that is creating the error.

Comment: If the answer below solves your issue don't for get to accept the answer

Comment: the line of code for the error was `[15:37:03]: No such file or directory - pod`

Answer (score 7):

You probably haven't installed cocoapods

```
$ gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install cocoapods tool to run pod install command. to do that, open terminal then run this command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

if you want to update the tool on other time run this command:

```
sudo gem update cocoapods
```